# normalizing input string before searching through List c#

Tags: c#, .net, regex, winforms

I am creating a multi form application which has a series of validation test before the user can save the form. One of those validation functions needs evaluate if the user has entered certain keywords, such as 'Unkown', 'TBA', 'N/A'.I need to begin by normalizing the input string, to strip all unwanted characters  such as Whitespace, and  extra casing such as 'UNkown', 'tBA'. This then needs to be checked against my `list`.

This is my current method however my regex doesn't normalize my input string correctly and will pass validation if there is a space in-front of the word

```
public bool useUnkownEntity(string strTest)
{  
    Regex rgx = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z]");


    List<string> unkown = new List<string> { "Unkown", "tba", "tbc","N/a"};
    useUnkownEntity(rgx.Replace(strTest, ""));

    if (unkown.Contains(strTest, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("please refre to the unkown ENtity within");
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}
```

My desired result be false if any of the desired words are found iregardless if they are not a exact match. What would be the best approach, to capture all possibilities a user may enter to get passed validation.

This is the event I am calling the method from

```
private void txt_SurName_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {   // Convert User input to TitleCase
            if (useUnkownEntity(txt_SurName.Text))
            {
                return; 

            }
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt_SurName.Text))
            {
                epSurname.Clear(); _IsValid = true;
            }

            else if (util.IsAllLetters(txt_SurName.Text))
            {
                epSurname.Clear(); txt_SurName.Text = util.ToTitle(txt_SurName.Text); _IsValid = true;
            }

            else
            {
                epSurname.SetError(txt_SurName, "InValid Surname"); _IsValid = false;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Perhaps you wanted to write `new Regex(@"[^a-zA-Z]")` to match any char but an ASCII letter.

Comment: I tried that however it now gives me a null execption

Comment: And the answer on the duplicate is not what I need also, I need to allow for symbols such as N/A

Comment: Reformulate what you need, it is not clear what you need. Were you trying to modify `strTest`? Then why use `useUnkownEntity(rgx.Replace(strTest, ""));`? I guess it should be `strTest = rgx.Replace(strTest, "");`

Comment: Your method appears to be recursive - with no exit from the recursion - can you show your real code.

Comment: What I need is to simply display a message box if any of the words have been found in ignoring the format of the input

Comment: Ive added the code where the method is being called

Comment: I did not initially have the regex and just the contains however it didn't take into account whitespace

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer so far, it ignores casing but not spacing, if I enter a few spaces at the beginning of the word it will fail, just as it will if a / is forgotten on N/A.

```
 public bool useUnkownEntity(string strTest)
        {
            Regex rgx = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z/s/ ]");
            List<string> unkown = new List<string> { "Unkown", "tba", "tbc","N/A"};
              strTest = rgx.Replace(strTest, "");
            if (unkown.Contains(strTest, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please refer to the unkown Entity within!!");
                return false;
            }
            return true;

        }
```